# How do I create a virtual directory to redirect to another virtual directory in IIS

Tags: iis, redirect, virtualdirectories

I'm still new to IIS, what I want to do is create multiple Virtual Directories for each version of our software by version number, so that we can do regression testing on each of the configurations.

So what I want to do is this:

app_1.2.3.4 as a virtual directory.

And then have a Virtual directory "app" which redirects to a value I set, such as app_1.0.0.0 for instance.

Is this possible from IIS, or do I need some magic asp.net or javascript to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, completely possible.  Right click on the "app" VD and set it to be a (non-permanent) redirect to the current version.